# There's a long delay in this query that I need to resolve

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, optimization, execution-plan

This is a multi-tenant/portal DNN (formally DotNetNuke) database, and a core query as part of the registration process seems to be terribly slow.

Here it is:

```
declare @PortalID int = 0;

SELECT R.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM   dbo.[UserRoles] U 
     WHERE  U.RoleID = R.RoleID 
            AND U.Status = 1 
            AND (U.EffectiveDate < GETDATE() OR U.EffectiveDate IS NULL)
            AND (U.ExpiryDate > GETDATE() OR U.ExpiryDate IS NULL)) AS UserCount
FROM  dbo.[Roles] R
WHERE (R.PortalId = @PortalID OR R.PortalId is null)
      AND (R.RoleId >= 0) 
ORDER BY R.RoleName
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PortalId UNKNOWN))
```

I'll be honest, I haven't used optimization options before. What's critical here is it's a multi-portal site so what I change I have to be absolutely sure it doesn't spring up a nasty gotcha down the road.

I'm assuming the execution plan has to accommodate potential nulls in the @PortalID that of which is a parameter within the stored procedure. My example code above is extracted and I'm setting the @PortalID to 0.

The core developers created this procedure, and response times to get assistance vary so I'm asking here.

Is there a risk to changing this optimization to:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PortalId = 0))
```

This is the main portal used and is by far the most important. The core developers have to account for sites that have hundreds or even thousands of portals.

Even so, changing this leaves no guarantee of future upgrades as they may overwrite it. Just trying to track down a problem and want to know of a fail-safe way to optimize this query.

So if I set:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PortalID = 0))
```

It runs fast... 10x faster.

But I'm uncertain of caching or other problems that may arise from changing this.

Comment: The query plan will be optimized for when PortalID = 0, can PortalID be other values? The trade off could be that for example you put PortalID = 1, then you will get a plan optimized for portalID = 0. It depends on how the data in your tables is distributed. As an other way around this, IMO, using option(recompile) on queries that are not executed a lot is fine, granted that you have the CPU power to  the extra compiles.

Comment: @RandiVertongen It's a CMS which is built to handle thousands of portals, but in this case the primary workhorse is portalID 0. No risk to this change other than performance decrease in other portals?

Comment: Also what would be the purpose or benefit when it's currently set to UNKNOWN

Comment: [Optimize for… Mediocre?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/optimize-for-unknown-sql-server-parameter-sniffing/)

Comment: Yes the risk is a performance hit for any other PortalID that is not 0. How big that would be, is up to you to test & monitor.

Comment: is the db compatibility level to 2016 ? Also is `QUERY_OPTIMIZER_HOTFIXES = ON` ?

Comment: You can also consider to add PortalId literally. This is not a best practice in general but for the specific instance it will ensure each portal gets its own query with plan.

Answer (score 2):

**Testing the Impact that OPTION(OPTIMIZE FOR @PORTALID = 0) could have**

**Create the tables**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[Roles]
(
RoleID INT PRIMARY KEY,
PortalId INT,
RoleName 
varchar(255)
)

CREATE TABLE DBO.[UserRoles]
(
UserRoleID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
RoleID INT FOREIGN KEY(RoleID) REFERENCES dbo.roles,
Status int default (1),
EffectiveDate datetime2,
ExpiryDate datetime2
)
```

**Insert some data into roles**

```
INSERT INTO DBO.Roles(RoleID,PortalId,RoleName) 
VALUES(1,0,'Role1') -- 1 value with portal id = 0


DECLARE @ID INT = 2
WHILE @ID < 1000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO DBO.Roles(RoleID,PortalId,RoleName) 
VALUES(@ID,1,'Role2') -- 998 rows with @PortalID = 1

SET @ID += 1
END
```

**Insert some data into UserRoles**

```
DECLARE @ID INT = 1
WHILE @ID < 1000 
BEGIN

INSERT INTO DBO.[UserRoles](RoleID,EffectiveDate,ExpiryDate)
VALUES(@ID,getdate(),NULL) -- one user role for each role id.

SET @ID += 1
END
```

**Testing the query with @PortalID = 0 and @PortalID = 1**

**@PortalID = 0**

```
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON;
declare @PortalID int = 0
SELECT R.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[UserRoles] U 
     WHERE U.RoleID = R.RoleID 
     AND U.Status = 1 
     AND (U.EffectiveDate < GETDATE() OR U.EffectiveDate IS NULL)
     AND (U.ExpiryDate > GETDATE() OR U.ExpiryDate IS NULL)) AS UserCount
 FROM dbo.[Roles] R
 WHERE (R.PortalId = @PortalID OR R.PortalId is null)
AND (R.RoleId >= 0) 
ORDER BY R.RoleName
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PortalId = 0))
```

[image]
*The ususal scan's since we don't have indexes*

[image]
*The expectations match 100%*

**@PortalID = 1**

```
declare @PortalID int = 1
SELECT R.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[UserRoles] U 
     WHERE U.RoleID = R.RoleID 
     AND U.Status = 1 
     AND (U.EffectiveDate < GETDATE() OR U.EffectiveDate IS NULL)
     AND (U.ExpiryDate > GETDATE() OR U.ExpiryDate IS NULL)) AS UserCount
 FROM dbo.[Roles] R
 WHERE (R.PortalId = @PortalID OR R.PortalId is null)
AND (R.RoleId >= 0) 
ORDER BY R.RoleName
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PortalId = 0))
```

[image]

*That's gonna hurt on bigger tables*

[image]
*Low expectations*

**What if we run it without the optimize for? Spoiler: (This creates a new execution plan)**

```
declare @PortalID int = 1
SELECT R.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.[UserRoles] U 
     WHERE U.RoleID = R.RoleID 
     AND U.Status = 1 
     AND (U.EffectiveDate < GETDATE() OR U.EffectiveDate IS NULL)
     AND (U.ExpiryDate > GETDATE() OR U.ExpiryDate IS NULL)) AS UserCount
 FROM dbo.[Roles] R
 WHERE (R.PortalId = @PortalID OR R.PortalId is null)
AND (R.RoleId >= 0) 
ORDER BY R.RoleName
```

[image]
*That's better*

**TL;DR**

As is usual, YMMV.

What will happen when implementing something like this depends on the indexes, the data, and all the other things SQL Server takes into account when creating an execution plan. How much the query is executed with certain parameters, ....

This is just to show what might happen if you implement `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@PortalId = 0))` on a production system. 
In the end it is up to you to test the possible outcomes, and what is best for your system. 
You could opt to use the query as it is and deal with parameter sniffing, to use optimize for unkown so the SQL Server engine will use stats and other heuristics to optimize its execution plan, to use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` as to not cache the plan but create it on each execution, to use `OPTION( OPTIMIZE FOR @PortalId = 0)`, but deal with queries that using a different value, as they might go slower, ... .

Comment: When I test this on the real database, it takes 4 seconds with no optimize option, same with `unknown`. I'm going to do some more testing with your examples and look at the output. Just wanted to provide some quick feedback.

Comment: Alright great, thanks for the feedback :)